# How to set Eureka client version?

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I have a spring boot application and Eureka ( spring-cloud) used for service discovery. I need to set Eureka client version as specified in this bean https://github.com/Netflix/eureka/blob/master/eureka-client/src/main/java/com/netflix/appinfo/InstanceInfo.java - version parameter. But I cannot find the application property to set this. I have tried,

```
eureka.client.version=1.0
eureka.instance.version=1.0
```

but that does not set com.netflix.appinfo.InstanceInfo.version property. Does someone knows what property should I set ?

Comment: It should be the latter. Where are you trying to set it.

Comment: @spencergibb At eureka client application.properties. When eureka client registers with server I capture that event and check weather client has compatible ( acceptable) version.